# Extracting ColumnNames with a specific String using Regular Expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

I have a dataframe as follows: ( a sample shown below. It has similar form of more than 10000 cols)

```
   df 
        
    CONT  RF GHT AT@RT@NAS@VRT=Y ON@RV@NAS@VTP=Y  QR@RZ@RG@NVR@VPQ=N  QR@RZ@RG@NAS@VVV=N
     1    3   4     5                 7                11                 12
     10   2   5     9                 6                11                 16
```

So what I want to do is to extract the columns 'CONT', 'RF' and all the columns with the pattern '@NAS'

So my output dataframe ( in the example should be like):

```
 df_out 
        
    CONT  RF AT@RT@NAS@VRT=Y ON@RV@NAS@VTP=Y  QR@RZ@RG@NAS@VVV=N 
     1    3       5                 7                11                 
     10   2       9                 6                11
```

I have tried the following, but it is not extracting the columns with '@NAS'

```
   selCols = ["CONT", "RF",  "@NAS*"]
   cols = df.columns
   msk_pt = '|'.join(selCols)
   req = re.compile(msk_pt)

   newCols = [line for line in cols if req.match(line)] 

   df_out = df[newCols]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: use `@NAS` instead of @NAS*，and re.search

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [2635]: res = pd.concat([df[['CONT', 'RF']], df.filter(like='@NAS')], axis=1)

In [2636]: res
Out[2636]: 
   CONT  RF  AT@RT@NAS@VRT=Y  ON@RV@NAS@VTP=Y  QR@RZ@RG@NAS@VVV=N
0     1   3                5                7                  12
1    10   2                9                6                  16
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str.contains` method in `df.columns` to apply regexp.

```
cond = df.columns.str.contains('CONT|RF|@NAS')
df[df.columns[cond]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `[...]` selecting with `isin` and `str.contains`:

```
df_out = df[df.columns[df.columns.isin(['CONT', 'RF']) | df.columns.str.contains('@NAS')]]
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   CONT  RF  AT@RT@NAS@VRT=Y  ON@RV@NAS@VTP=Y  QR@RZ@RG@NAS@VVV=N
0     1   3                5                7                  12
1    10   2                9                6                  16
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension with `re.search`:

```py
pattern = r'^(?:CONT|RF|.*@NAS.*)$'
cols = df.columns
newCols = [c for c in cols if re.search(pattern, c)]
df_out = df[newCols]
```

Comment: with your pattern we could also use `str.contains` on `df.columns` and use `loc` directly like :->  `df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains(pattern)]` or with `df.filter`:->  `df.filter(regex=pattern)`  :-)

Comment: @anky Thanks for the comment.  The OP's use of regular Python set me off in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost done, I would make a little change:

```
   import re

   COLUMNS_REGEX = "CONT|RF|@NAS"
   cols = df.columns
   newCols = [col for col in cols if re.search(COLUMNS_REGEX, col)]
   df_out = df[newCols]
```